# UCWA application message received event triggers multiple times

Tags: c#, skype, skype-for-business, ucwa

I have created a UCWA based bot application in C# for communicating with Skype for Business server. I am able to connect to server and able to send messages to other people. All events are received using P-Get (Pending Get) approach as mentioned in UCWA documentation.

Whenever any one sends me a message, I am getting messages more than once. The event channel is triggered as many times as the P-Get response is received. Sometimes I am not getting the messages too.
I have created a separate thread to handle P-Get events.

Can anyone please point out what is the reason behind this and how to fix it?

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: are you 100% sure that it has to do with some issues on how the events are dispatched, and not with some issues in your code in handling the Event Channel messages? I'd try to trace the communication with a tool such as Fiddler, to confirm the issue is with the events dispatched or how you handle the incoming events

Comment: Thanks @MassimoProta for the reply.. 
There was an issue in the code.. I have used a different events uri.